# How to access application.properties from freemarker template

Tags: spring-boot, templates, freemarker, properties-file

In a freemarker template, we can access spring messages.properties like so

messages.properties:

```
...
my.message=foo
...
```

example.ftl:

```
<@spring.message 'my.messsage'/>
```

output:

```
foo
```

is there a way to do the same for properties defined in application.properties and other active profiles? Trying to access the same way has yielded the follwing error:

```
No message found under code 'my.prop' for locale 'xx_XX'
```

Edit:
I have seen some examples of doing so with extra configurations to dependencies, but I was looking for an easier way as those suggestions would severely impact current code

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just prefix them with their reference or otherwise....

So instead of my.message, it might be app.someProperty

Comment: does this mean that in my example if I had `my.property` in `application.properties` it would be `app.my.property`?